# The future of the orbit of a point is a closed set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

$X$ is a metric space and $f: X  \rightarrow X$ is a dynamical system.

Prove: $w(x_{0})$ is closed.

Here the set $w(x_{0})$ is the future of the orbit of $x_0$, defined as $$\omega(x_0) = \{y \mid \exists (n_k)\, n_k \to \infty, f^{n_k}(x_0) \to y\}$$

Comment: Do you mean $\omega(x_0) = \{y \mid \exists (n_k)\, n_k \to \infty, f^{n_k}(x_0) \to y\}$?

Comment: @martini yes. It is the definition of $w(x_{0})$.

Comment: If $X$ is a metric space, the title "Holomorphic Dynamics" was  out of place. Actually, titles like "Holomorphic Dynamics" are never a good choice: the title should be a lot more specific than the name of some area of mathematics.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. You are right, thx very much.